# Wmic does not work on preinstalled Win10

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I have little problem with my computer. It suddenly stop working so I wanted to clean format it. It HP Pavilion x2. I wanted to retrieve my Windows product key. So I went to the bios and saw this line:
windows:

[image: [![windows][1]][1] (sorry not able to post whole image < 10 reps)]

I thought that is everything is OK. Went to BIOS (opened `cmd` from bootable USB) typed the command:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

[image: result]

So what's wrong with this. Bios states that I have preinstalled OS so probably the key should be there right? Is is possible that license is on some kind of partition?

Where can I find my key?

Comment: You don't need a key for WIn10; it's tied to the hardware & will be recognised automatically.

Comment: Remove `OA3x` from your command.

Comment: Product key is stored in the uefi firmware, windows install will get it from there.

Comment: @Moab So you are saying that i cannot clean all partition? Because i am not able to install clean windows. Because win10 is not able configurate boot settings.

Comment: Sure you can, but why would you want to?

Comment: @Moab because i am not able to install my clean windows. At the end of all installation message is display: instalation canceled because windows wan't able to configure boot settings and i want to be sure that erase my whole disc won't clear my windows key storaged on some efi or other weird partition that i have